# Intent between 2 activities

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I'm stuck with this 2 activities. The Main one has to login with facebook credentials (if a user has logged recently, the app uses the token saved earlier), then takes user's id, saves it into the intent via the LoggedActivity is called. But when i try to extract data from intent in second activity, it says it is empty! Help me pls!

**EDIT**

> I discovered the problem but I cant resolve it. 
>   Request.executeBatchAsync(request) launches a thread via I get user's id. The problem is that I have to wait for the thread to complete for getting the id, so it can be saved in the Intent! There is no method in FB API for doing it... Help me pls, I'm almost done :D

** FINAL EDIT**

> solved! The problemwas as I said in the last edit. I just solved it creating the intent inside the onCompleted method :D Thanks to all!

MainActivity

```
SharedPreferences sp;
AccessToken token;
private Button connect;
private String id;
private String access_token;
private String expires;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    connect=(Button)findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,LoggedActivity.class);
    connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
                openFacebook();
        }
    });

    sp=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    access_token=sp.getString("access_token", null);
    expires=sp.getString("access_expires",null);

    if (access_token!=null  && expires!=null)
    {
        token = AccessToken.createFromExistingAccessToken(access_token,null, null, AccessTokenSource.TEST_USER, null);
        if (token!=null)
        {
            Session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(this,token,new Session.StatusCallback() 
            {
                // callback when session changes state

                @Override
                public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
                {
                    if (session.isOpened()) 
                    {
                        Request request =  Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback() {       
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
                        {                                
                            if (user != null) 
                            {
                                id=user.getId();    
                            }

                        }
                        });

                        Request.executeBatchAsync(request); 
                    }
                }
            });

            myIntent.putExtra("Id", id);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        }  
    }    
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void openFacebook()
{
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback()
    {   
        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
        {
            if (session.isOpened()) 
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoggedActivity.class);
                Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putString("access_token",session.getAccessToken());
                editor.putString("access_expires",session.getExpirationDate().toString());
                editor.commit();

                Request request =  Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback() {       
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
                {                                
                    if (user != null) 
                    {
                        id=user.getId();
                    }

                }
                });

                Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
                myIntent.putExtra("Id", id);

                startActivity(myIntent);
            }

        }
    }); 
}
```

LoggedActivity

```
     private ProfilePictureView profilePicture;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    String id = myIntent.getStringExtra("Id"); 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.app_main);

    profilePicture = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.userImage);
    profilePicture.setProfileId(id);

}


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You may just need to move the getIntent() to below the super.onCreate(). It looks like you are doing it right.

Comment: @Andrew
no dude, tried to move it as you said, but nothing changed :(

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or does getStringExtra() just return null?

Comment: It returns null! @Andrew

Comment: Are you sure you are setting `id` in MainActivity?? Try a toast and check if `id` has value in it..

Comment: The problem is id is printed in the toast after getting id qith id=user.getId() but not outside that inner class.... What have I to do? @Lal

Comment: Pardon..i dint understand..Which inner class are you talking abt???

Comment: change `private String id;` to public and check..

Comment: check my edit. I found the problem :D @Lal

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
myIntent.putExtra("Id", id);
```

Try to use

```
myIntent.getExtras().putString("Id", id);
```

Comment: There is no putString method for Intent. I'm guessing you meant to mention using a Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You should have used

```
String myString= intent.getExtras().getString("id");
```

to get the string in the LogIn Activity

Answer (score 0):

When you receive message it comes in the form of intent so just add two lines in your code:

```
Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
//check if extras is not null
If(extras!=null)
String msg=(string)extras.get("message");//remember here message is the key that you send from the server...
```

Wish it would help you

Comment: i am not home right now. I will try it asap. Ty for the answer